# Is $15 USD for a hotel/motel room really that "unthinkably low"?

Tags: united-states, housing, travel, cost-of-living

I just watched a video where a guy tried to claim that the hotel or motel room he was going to meet somebody at and pay for costs "$15", in the USA. I assume he means "per night".

While money is not worth almost anything compared to what it used to, is fifteen US dollars that *really* "suspiciously" cheap?

I remember an old TV episode called "Man in a four-dollar room", which was apparently a cheap USA "hotel" (more like apartment) room in the 1960s. Even that seemed like a high price to me for the time and how much you could get for a "quarter" or "dime" in those days.

If I have to pay far more than $15 per night, I could definitely not stay long anywhere in the USA (or probably anywhere in the "rich" world).

Comment: Yes, this is unthinkably low for basically any area in the U.S. In many places, it'd be unthinkable to pay less than $150/night for a hotel room, but there are plenty of areas where you'd pay in the region of $50 - $100/night for a room.

Comment: As another data point, Expedia shows a small selection of rooms for under $40/night, but even these are all $30+. Even a hostel will probably [start around $20/night](https://www.tripsavvy.com/cost-of-hostels-3150061)

Comment: What is the date of the video, though?  Prices have changed a lot over past decades.  For instance, there's a chain of budget motels named "Motel 6". which got its name because it originally (in 1960) charged $6/night: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motel_6

Comment: This might be better suited to Travel than personal finance. The USA is a big place with highly varying costs depending on where you are, so it's possible a room could be that cheap somewhere, though it's definitely not the norm. You could also try searching travel sites to see typical hotel prices in the areas you're interested in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mopve to Travel.SE, questions about hourly rates, in fictional cinema, for prostitution hotels, are - generally speaking - completely irrelevant here

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you assumed wrong that the price was 15 dollars a night, maybe it was 15 dollars a hour. After all the guy in your movie was using the hotel room not to sleep but to meet someone.